# Google Autocomplete Script Truncates Results Based on Input String in Python 2.7.12

Tags: python, autocomplete

Before I get into details, note that I'm not a programmer. Just learning python and starting to get a handle on things. Now to the issue at hand:

I adapted an [autocomplete string generator](https://github.com/rastrau/Google-Autocomplete-analysis/blob/master/autocomplete_search.py) to add a list of terms to a question. It seems to be almost working, but I'm getting hung up on some formatting issues in the output file.

Here's the adapted code (it's overkill, but I'm looking to get something working before improving it).

```
import urllib, urllib2
import json
import time
import codecs

inFile = 'keywordFile.txt'
sep = ','
keywordField = 'keyword'
outFile = 'autoCompFile.txt'

google_endpoint = 'http://google.com/complete/search?output=firefox&q='

def find_index(fieldname, inFile):
    with open(inFile, 'r') as f:
        header = f.readline().rstrip().split(sep)
        i = 0
        for i in range(0, len(header)):
            if header[i] == fieldname:
                return i
                break
        else:
            return -1

def build_phrase(keyword):     
    phrase = u'why did'
    return u'%s %s' % (phrase, keyword)

def query_google(phrase):
    url = '%s%s' % (google_endpoint, urllib.quote_plus(phrase))
    data = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    data = json.load(data)
    results = [result.replace(phrase.lower(), '') for result in data[1]]
    return results

kwIndex = find_index(keywordField, inFile)

with codecs.open(inFile, 'r', 'utf-8') as f:

    with codecs.open(outFile, 'w', 'utf-8') as f_out:
        f_out.write('keyword, autocomplete phrase\n')

        data = f.readlines()
        for record in data[1:]:
            time.sleep(0.3)

            record = record.rstrip()
            items = record.split(sep)
            kw = items[kwIndex]

            phrase = build_phrase(kw)
            results = query_google(phrase)
            if len(results) > 0:
                for result in results:
                    f_out.write('%s, %s, %s\n' % (kw, phrase, result))
            else:
                f_out.write('%s, %s\n' % (kw, phrase))
```

Something in the code is causing the "result" to truncate if it includes the exact wording of the built phrase. Example output:

- bureaucracy, why did bureaucracy,  develop in early governments
- bureaucracy, why did bureaucracy,  become a branch of government
- bureaucracy, why did bureaucracy,  grow in the 20th century
- bureaucracy, why did bureaucracy, why did a bureaucracy develop in egypt
- bureaucracy, why did bureaucracy, why did weber consider bureaucracy ideal
- bureaucracy, why did bureaucracy, why did the federal bureaucracy grown
- bureaucracy, why did bureaucracy, why did weber study bureaucracy
- bureaucracy, why did bureaucracy, why did max weber fear bureaucracy

Ideally, I would like to get the keyword and a full results string without any kind of truncation. So I want both cases to look like this:

- bureaucracy, why did bureaucracy, why did bureaucracy become a branch of government?
- bureaucracy, why did bureaucracy, why did a bureaucracy develop in egypt

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with Python... Seems more like how the Google API is implemented.
EDIT: actually, after reading your question again the problem is clear:
`results = [result.replace(phrase.lower(), '') for result in data[1]]`
You're getting rid of the phrase from your results... That's exactly what the code does. Answer will follow below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're removing the phrase from your results. So your code is doing exactly what you wrote it to do...

Remove this line:

```
results = [result.replace(phrase.lower(), '') for result in data[1]]
```

Comment: It worked when I replaced that line with results = data[1]. Thanks for pinpointing where things were going wrong! Very grateful!